# Error when trying to install sublime text on ubuntu in virtualbox (virtualbox-guest-dkms)

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox version 6.1.16 and Ubuntu 20.04.01. Following the steps to install sublime text ([here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html)), the second command ("Ensure apt is set up to work with https sources") I receive the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (2.0.2ubuntu0.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm10
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up virtualbox-guest-dkms (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-guest-6.1.10 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-guest-6.1.10 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-34-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-34-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-guest-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-guest-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-guest-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-guest-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It does appear to install if I just ignore the error, but I would like to make sure I am not overlooking something.

Comment: You didn't install the Guest Additions properly. Remove them and install as I wrote previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
 sudo apt purge virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

Then go to Devices menu of the virtual machine and install Guest Additions from there.